# Does Grave Injustice reduce the cooldown on Spirit Vessel?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Is there any evidence, stated by Blizzard or others, that the cooldown of Spirit Vessel is reduced whenever Grave Injustice is triggered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No, Spirit Vessel is not affected by the cooldown reduction of Grave Injustice.

Which is a little counter intuitive, as the text on Grave Injustice would indicate that all abilities have their cooldowns reduced:

> Whenever an enemy dies within 8 yards, regain 2% of your maximum Life and Mana and the cooldown on all of your abilities is reduced by 1 second. This range is extended by items that increase your gold pickup radius.

Fundamentally though, the cheat-death effect of Spirit Vessel is more of a proc than a cooldown. This is backed up in the [many](http://d3up.com/guide/9/wd-grave-injustice-build) [build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7199030049) [discussions](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5208782852) around the use of these abilities together, including [this quote](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7199030049):

> It does not sadly. Would be an absolutely amazing, and quite overpowered, change if it were to ever happen.

While Grave Injustice does not reduce the cooldown for the cheat-death proc, it will stack with the cooldown reduction for abilities such as Spirit Walk.

Comment: I think you read my original question wrong. I was asking about Spirit Vessel, not Spirit Walk. All three of the links talk about reducing the cooldown on Spirit Walk, and many of the builds posted don't even have Spirit Vessel as a passive skill.

Comment: @SocioMatt you are correct, my apologies - give me a moment and I will correct my blindness.

Answer (score 0):

No, Spirit Vessel can not activate more than stated by the tooltip, this is because the ability itself never goes on cooldown, but rather, the witchdoctor gets a debuff that cancels a second activation of Spirit Vessel.